# Custom region does not show up in a Drupal Sub theme

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-theming, drupal-themes

I am attempting to create a custom region for my Drupal 7 sub theme. The process I am following is:

1) Specify sub region in .info file of subtheme like this:
   regions['sub_region'] = Sub region
2) In the page.tpl.php file, 
    print render($page['sub_region']);  at the location where I wish the sub region would appear.

3) Cleared the Cache

However, this new sub region does not appear in my Blocks.

Anybody have pointers as to what I am doing wrong ? Or need to do more

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth having a read of [this](http://drupal.org/node/225125), specially this section.

> Region inheritance
>
> Sub-themes do not inherit custom regions from a parent theme. If you
>   are using custom regions, you should copy the region declarations from
>   the parent theme's .info file. Be sure your sub-theme's page.tpl.php
>   file matches the sub-theme's region settings.

**EDIT**

[image]

On your blocks page in the top right corner are tabs so you can set different blocks on different themes. Are you selecting the sub theme?

Comment: the custom region has been added to my sub theme, not to the main theme, I have to downvote since you did not read the question carefully

Comment: Have you actually tried putting it in the main theme and copying the .info file?

Comment: Are selecting your sub theme using the tabs on the blocks page?

Comment: don't understand your last comment, can you elaborate?

Comment: Was this the answer to your question?

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax for the region declaration in .info is incorrect. There should not be single quotes wrapping the region name.

```
regions[sub_region] = Sub region
```

[Documentation for .info file](http://drupal.org/node/171205)

Comment: actually having inverted quotes or not, did not make a difference.